# Error al definiir los metodos de una clase

Tags: c++, poo, método

tengo este `date.h`, donde tengo una clase `Date`. Defino mis metodos y después los implemento en un `date.cpp` pero el compilador me lanza errores de:

> error: "metodo...." previously defined here. y error: redefinition of "metodo....".

Me da error y no se por qué. No se lo qué estoy haciendo mal. Ayuda.

codigos:

date.h:

```
#ifndef DATE_H_INCLUDED
#define DATE_H_INCLUDED


using namespace std;

class Date {
private:
    int year;
    int day;
    int month;
    string fullDate;
public:
    int getYear();
    int getDay();
    int getMonth();
    string getFullDate();
    void setYear(const int&);
    void setDay(const int&);
    void setMonth(const int&);
    void _fullDate();
};
```

y date.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "date.h"
using namespace std;

int Date::getYear(){
    return year;
    }

int Date::getDay(){
    return day;
    }

int Date::getMonth(){
    return month;
    }

string Date::getFullDate(){
    return fullDate;
    }

void Date::setYear(const int& x){
    year = x;
    }

void Date::setDay(const int& x){
    day = x;
    }

void Date::setMonth(const int& x) {
    month = x;
    }

void Date::_fullDate(){
    stringstream full;
    full << day << "/" << month << "/" << year;
    fullDate = full.str();
}



#endif // DATE_H_INCLUDED
```

Answer (score 3):

He probado el código que has pasado y lo he corregido hasta eliminar el error de compilación. Se reduce a:

> - Incluir la librería string.
> - El correcto uso de la técnica del preprocesado para no incluir varias veces el mismo archivo de encabezado es agregarlo el *#endif* al final del fichero de la interfaz no de la implementación.

El fichero *date.h*

```
#ifndef DATE_H_INCLUDED
#define DATE_H_INCLUDED
#include <string> // para que pueda emplear los string

using namespace std;

class Date {
private:
    int year;
    int day;
    int month;
    string fullDate;
public:
    int getYear();
    int getDay();
    int getMonth();
    string getFullDate();
    void setYear(const int&);
    void setDay(const int&);
    void setMonth(const int&);
    void _fullDate();
};

#endif // se añade al fichero .h para evitar que un fichero de encabezado se incluya varias veces
```

El fichero *date.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "date.h"
using namespace std;

int Date::getYear(){
    return year;
}

int Date::getDay(){
    return day;
}

int Date::getMonth(){
    return month;
}

string Date::getFullDate(){
    return fullDate;
}

void Date::setYear(const int& x){
    year = x;
}

void Date::setDay(const int& x){
    day = x;
}

void Date::setMonth(const int& x) {
    month = x;
}

void Date::_fullDate(){
    stringstream full;
    full << day << "/" << month << "/" << year;
    fullDate = full.str();
}
```